# determining the pdf of the limiting distribution

Tags: probability-theory

$X_1$, $X_2$,... are iid random variables having pdf
$$f(x)=3x^2 I_{(0,1)}(x)$$

We also have that $V_n = n^{1/3}$ min$(X_1,...,X_n)$ and $W_n = n^{1/3}$ max$(X_1,...,X_n)$.

a.) Consider the sequence $V_1, V_2,...$ and give the pmf or pdf of the limiting distribution

b.) Consider the sequence $W_1, W_2,...$ and give the pmf or pdf of the limiting distribution

I know how to solve a problem like this when $X_1, X_2,...$ are uniform iid random variables, but I am having trouble figuring out how to start this problem given that the pdf is different.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Find expressions for $\mathsf{P}(V_n>v)$ and $\mathsf{P}(W_n<w)$ and look what happens to these expressions if $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Where does the pdf for $X_1, X_2,...$ come in? Is that something that has to be used to determine those expressions?

Comment: Based on the pdf you can find expressions like $P(X_1>x)$ and $P(X_1<x)$. Then you can find $P(V_n>v)$ on base of $V_n>v\iff X_1>vn^{-\frac13}\wedge\cdots\wedge X_n>vn^{-\frac13}$. Likewise you can find an expression for $P(W_n<w)$.